# Finding Crossing sequences 2-DFA

Tags: automata, dfa, nfa

I am trying to build NFA from 2-way DFA but i can't get the idea of right/left matching that is the conversion built on as decribed here.

http://smartclassacademy.blogspot.cz/2012/11/two-way-finite-automata.html

Can someone explain it in other words?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs682/2008sp/Handouts/2DFA.pdf) would take you to a pdf file which explains 2-DFA and regular DFA conversion.

P.S : Converting it to a normal DFA can be tedious as it involves
constructing and identifying identical tables.(Spent some time with it).